# Java Timer going off every hour Sat-Sun

Tags: java

I have a Timer class that I want to schedule to run for 30 minutes and for it to execute every hour from Saturday at 12AM to Sunday at midnight.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a java.util.Timer, a javax.swing.Timer or something else?

Comment: @StephenC I am talking about java.util.Timer, sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.util.Timer` class does not have the functionality to do this using repeated tasks:

- You cannot configure a `Timer` to >>stop<< running repeated tasks at a given time
- The execution model for repeated tasks is "fixed-delay execution"; i.e. a new task is scheduled based on the end-point of the previous task.  That results in time slippage ... if tasks take a long time.

The simple solution is:

- create a single `Timer` object
- use `schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)` in a loop to schedule 48 separate tasks, starting on each hour in the range that you require.

According to the javadoc, `Timer` is scalable and should be able to cope with lots of scheduled tasks efficiently.

---

The above does not deal with the requirement that each task runs for 30 minutes.  It is not clear what that actually means, but if you want the task to run for *no more than* 30 minutes, then you need to implement a "watch dog" that interrupts the thread running the task when its time is up.  The task needs to be implemented to check for and/or handle thread interrupts appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You could have a loop run and in the loop just sleep for an hour or however long you wanted. Would something like this work?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  // do whatever you want to do
  try {
    // Sleep for an hour
    Thread.sleep(6000000);
  catch(InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

I might have misunderstood the question... but if that's what you wanted.. then... yay?